# How to update value every x seconds or when value from room database is changes

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-room, android-mvvm

I'd like the variable `listOfPoints` to change every time when `workout.points` is changed or every "x" seconds.

```
var listOfPoints = emptyList<LatLng>()

var workoutId = viewModel.getAllWorkouts().collectAsState(null).value?.size

if(workoutId != null) {
   var workout = viewModel.getSpecifWorkout(workoutId).collectAsState(null).value
   if (workout != null) {
       listOfPoints = viewModel.convertStringToListOfLatLng(workout.points)
   }
}
```

Rest of code: https://github.com/DawidSiudeja/RunTracker/blob/main/app/src/main/java/com/example/runtracker/presentation/screens/active_workout/ActiveWorkout.kt

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the code above is part of a composable function, if so you can wrap the `if` block inside a `LaunchedEffect` with the key being `workout` as follows:

```
var listOfPoints by remember { mutableStateOf(emptyList<LatLng>()) }

var workoutId = viewModel.getAllWorkouts().collectAsState(null).value?.size

var workout = if(workoutId != null) {
    viewModel.getSpecifWorkout(workoutId).collectAsState(null).value
} else {
    null
}

LaunchedEffect(workout) {
    listOfPoints = if (workout != null) {
        viewModel.convertStringToListOfLatLng(workout.points)
    } else {
        null
    }

}
```

This way the block passed to `LaunchedEffect` will get called everytime `workout` changes but won't get unnecessarily called on each recomposition.

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/side-effects#launchedeffect